# Not getting decapsulated VXLAN traffic on second interface / file missing in /sys/class/net/vxlan1

Tags: networking

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 system in AWS. It has 2 interfaces configured (ens3 and ens4). ens3 is the primary interface. ens4 is getting VXLAN traffic. I've verified that the traffic is coming in on ens4 with a packet capture.

I setup a VXLAN interface by running these 2 commands:

```
$ ip link add vxlan1 type vxlan id 1 dev ens4 dstport 4789
$ ip link set vxlan1 up promisc on multicast on
```

I expected to see traffic on vxlan1, but nothing appears there at all

As a sanity check, I setup a second system, but with only 1 interface (ens3). I ran the same commands as above, adjusting the dev to ens3. There when I run a packet capture for the same VXLAN traffic I see it on vxlan1.

When I compare the contents of */sys/class/net/vxlan1* on both systems, the only difference I can find is that on the system with only 1 interface (where it works) I have this file, but it does not exist on the other system: **lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec  8 14:59 lower_ens3 -> ../../../pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/net/ens3**

What am I missing when setting up on a system with 2 interfaces?

Thanks!

TC

**Additional Information:**

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:42:65:b6:3c:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.26.136/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 1885sec preferred_lft 1885sec
    inet6 fe80::442:65ff:feb6:3c84/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:c4:e2:73:00:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.25.42/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 1885sec preferred_lft 1885sec
    inet6 fe80::4c4:e2ff:fe73:c6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vxlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:fd:94:2d:7d:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::68fd:94ff:fe2d:7df6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@ip-172-31-26-136:~# ip -br link;
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
ens3             UP             06:42:65:b6:3c:84 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
ens4             UP             06:c4:e2:73:00:c6 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
vxlan1           UNKNOWN        6a:fd:94:2d:7d:f6 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP>
root@ip-172-31-26-136:~# ip -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
ens3             UP             172.31.26.136/20 fe80::442:65ff:feb6:3c84/64
ens4             UP             172.31.25.42/20 fe80::4c4:e2ff:fe73:c6/64
vxlan1           UNKNOWN        fe80::68fd:94ff:fe2d:7df6/64
root@ip-172-31-26-136:~# ip route
default via 172.31.16.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 172.31.26.136 metric 100
default via 172.31.16.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 172.31.25.42 metric 100
172.31.16.0/20 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.26.136
172.31.16.0/20 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.25.42
172.31.16.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.26.136 metric 100
172.31.16.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.25.42 metric 100
root@ip-172-31-26-136:~# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Dec  8 18:59:45 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2557:593775]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2649:467409]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Dec  8 18:59:45 2021
```

Comment: You could give a more complete description of your network setup, using for example: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` as well as `iptables-save -c` (or `nft list ruleset`),  so your issue could be reproducible/reproduced.

Comment: Thanks @A.B I've added the information to the original post.

Comment: Looks like you have a routing issue with two default routes from two dhcp settings etc. ens4 might not be used correctly then since the routes use ens3. Also it looks like the two NICs are on the same Ethernet LAN and IP LAN which is almost always a bad idea. I don't really know what to do about this, but I'm at least telling what looks wrong.

Comment: I've removed the route, still does not work:
ip route
default via 172.31.16.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 172.31.26.136 metric 100
172.31.16.0/20 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.26.136
172.31.16.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.26.136 metric 100

Comment: take a VXLAN packet captured with tcpdump, for example IP a.b.c.d. then use `ip route get a.b.c.d` . If you don't get ens4 (but get ens3) don't expect it to work fine. Also what route(s) did you remove? ens4's? Wasn't that the interface configured to have vxlan?

Comment: I removed all the ens4 routes - ens4 is the interface getting the vxlan traffic.

Comment: Re the packet capture - did you want me to test with the IP address of the system sending the traffic to the system, the original sender IP, or the original receiver IP.  For example: IP 54.161.145.161.443 > 172.31.2.231.37804: Flags [P.], seq 693:1385, ack 17914, win 849, options [nop,nop,TS val 1784911040 ecr 1428011057], length 692
20:14:16.562794 IP 172.31.2.231.65488 > 172.31.25.42.4789: VXLAN, flags [I] (0x08), vni 1

Comment: The original sender IP. If it isn't routed using the same interface it's received on, that is asymmetric routing which has most chances to be dropped somewhere: your system, or your system's router

Comment: Reading again, I might have written incorrectly what I meant. I meant the source IP of the envelope of the VPN: a.b.c.d = 172.31.2.231

Comment: So, the only way I was able to get this to work, kinda, is by enabling asymetric routing and then setting an IP address on ens4 to be the same as the IP address where the VXLAN traffic is being directed to (172.31.25.42). I'd like to not have a dependency on the incoming IP address. Is there a way to setup a vxlan interface so that it will decapsulate all traffic received, even if not directed to the IP address included in the envelope?